# Solving equations using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, symbolic-math, integral, differentiation

I got an online question which I couldn’t understand.

The question is:

> Create a script to ask the user to create a random number using the following equation :
> [image: question]
>
> 1. Plot `x(t)` with customize the figure yellow and red color and dash line.
> 2. Solve the equation with symbolic and differentiate it.

I tried to solve it as following:

```
clc; clear all; 

syms x;
Xt = int(100*rand*sin(x),-100,100); 
plot(Xt);   % The first question 
Y = solve(100*rand*sin(x)); 
Y2 = diff(Xt,x);
```

The problem I face is that `Xt`, `Y` and `Y2` are all zeros.  Did I understand the question right? How to solve it?

Comment: Your integral evaluates to `-100 rand [cos(100)-cos(-100)] = zero`. What other result do you expect?

Comment: Thank you, but how does it ask to plot x(t) and customize the colors !! .. what's about the Y2, is that right too ?

Comment: Yes, very sure. It's the exact wording of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, could plot the functions with respect to `x`. Kinda concerned since the function is called `X(t)` though. Seems like it should be changing with respect to `t` or some kind of time variable. The colour and line properties can be configured by adding the short-hand for the colour followed by the line type in this case I used a dashed red line denoted as `r--` in the `fplot()` line. In this example, I also used `hold on` to add a yellow underline. If you need the figure background colour to be yellow add `set(gcf,'color','y');` to configure the current figure, `gcf`.  Not quite sure which portions or plots need the yellow colour. To plot symbolic functions using the `fplot()` function can be a useful method. This function can optionally take a second argument that is an array describing the horizontal/x-axis bounds/range to plot the function for. Also note that `rand` will only evaluate to doubles in the range from 0 to 1.

[image: Plot of Integrated and Derived Functions]

```
clear;
clc; 
clf;

syms x;

Xt = int(100*rand*sin(x)); 
Lower_Bound = -100;
Upper_Bound = 100;

subplot(2,1,1); fplot(Xt,[Lower_Bound Upper_Bound],'y');  
hold on
subplot(2,1,1); fplot(Xt,[Lower_Bound Upper_Bound],'r--'); 
title("Plot of X(t)");
xlabel("x"); ylabel("Amplitude");
hold off

Solution = int(100*rand*sin(x),Lower_Bound,Upper_Bound); 
Solution

Y2 = diff(Xt,x);

subplot(2,1,2); fplot(Y2,[Lower_Bound Upper_Bound])
title("Differentiation of X(t) -> Y(t)");
xlabel("x"); ylabel("Amplitude");
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**